# How to avoid not to fetch the data from backend to frontend because of how many time component render?

Tags: reactjs

Question, I'm creating this component named conversation, the conversation component will render based on many conversation user have from another user. After rendering it will pass a props to use on the child component of conversation named conversationList. My issue is because the conversation component will render based on no. of conversation, the dispatch function inside the conversationList will also rerender.

```
Conversation.js <-- If the no. of conversation in the backed is 2 it will render 2 times.
<div className='bg-lightGrey p-8 flex flex-col'>
            <div className='w-full flex flex-row'>
              <div class='bg-white w-1/4 mr-6 p-6 flex flex-col rounded-lg'>
                {conversationInfo.map((conversation, index) => (
                  <ConversationList
                    key={index}
                    currentConversation={conversation}
                    currentUser={currentAccountInfo._id}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
              <ChatBox
                socket={socket}
                roomId={roomId}
                user={currentAccountInfo}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

conversationList.js
    const ConversationList = ({ currentConversation, currentUser }) => {
      const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const accountGetById = useSelector((state) => state.accountGetById);
      const { accountById } = accountGetById;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const friendId = currentConversation.members.find(
          (id) => id !== currentUser
        );
    
        if (!accountById) {
          dispatch(getAccountById(friendId));
        }
    setUserId(accountById);
      }, [currentUser, accountById]);
    
      return (
        <>
        <div className='w-full'>
    <div className='mb-6 flex cursor-pointer'>
      <div className='relative'>
        <img
          className='mr-4 rounded-full'
          src={userId && userId.accountProfileUploaded}
          alt={userId && `${userId.firstName} ${userId.lastName}`}
          title={userId && `${userId.firstName} ${userId.lastName}`}
          style={{
            width: '42px',
            height: '42px',
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <p className='text-xs text-grey font-bold'>
        {userId && `${userId.firstName} ${userId.lastName}`}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
        </>
      );
    };
```

**Output:**
John Doe,
John Robert

**Output of the Code:**
John Doe,
John Deo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can try this

```
useEffect(() => {
    // to do
}, []);
```

Comment: What do you mean? I already tried that approach. The problem is because of the conversation component is need to render two times the value coming from the dispatch is also being called twice. It's like John Doe, John Doe, Katherine Doe, Katherine Doe.